# What is more taxing on the server? The number of databases or the amount of data?

Tags: database, multiple-databases

I have inherited a web application at work.  It creates new a MySQL database every time an user/account is added.  Each database usually goes up to 300mb but no more.  At 271 databases running on AWS RDS the web application is running like molasses.

There is one table in each database that holds 90% of the data and it holds the same data in all databases.  Therefore, I can take the data from this table and put in a separate database and have all the accounts connect to this database as well.  This will shrink the size of each database considerably.

However, I worry that it will not speed up the server because there are simply too many databases on it.  I am not DB admin and I apologize ahead of time if my train of thought does not make sense.  But I am very willing to learn.

Under the circumstances, should I try to shrink the number of databases or should I try to shrink the size of each database?  Would shrinking the size of each database really help?

Comment: Neither.  It's the query workload emitted against the server.....and the indexes...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : are you sure?  We had 127 databases running on a virtual environment. Increasing the RAM brought server back to life.  I doubt creating more databases increased the number of queries.

Comment: if you are not querying those databases, the extra load would be minimal. Also, if you are not querying them at all, why do you need to create them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should (seriously) look into reducing the number of database to *one.*

The concept of a single database per user is one of the more ... *interesting* ... ones I've heard - that's Pax showing an unusual amount of tact there :-)

Short of certain legislative requirements to separate different users from each other, there is really no valid reason to do this. Especially if you ever expect your database to scale.

300M times 300 accounts is about 90G and that's still a relatively small database in the scheme of things.

As you've stated, a lot of that information is duplicated so it won't get anywhere *near* that when you combine. If 90% of that 300M is shared, you'll end up with something like 30M multiplied by 300 accounts plus 270M shared, or under 10G.

I'm pretty certain some of our *configuration* tables are bigger than that :-)

Comment: Yes, it is a horrible design.  But I am stuck with it.  I know I will have to recommend scraping this app and making my own.  But I need to buy time.  Shrinking each database will be much easier than integrating all of them.  But will I benefit from that?

Comment: I don't know your business or the kind of data stored in your database. But sometimes you really do not want the data from one customer to end up with another customer. When you keep your data in seperate databases the chances for this to happen (due to a bug in a query) are almost nil.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the number of databases is the problem directly. But that's such an obvious sign of bad design that I bet there are issues elsewhere. For example, many optimizations are possible within a table but not across tables. So if you're constantly manipulating information of the same type but held in different tables, it's going to be absurdly slow.

Comment: so you are saying that I should Optimize the tables and queries rather than shrinking the size of each database?

Comment: Yes, assuming they need it, which I think is likely. Are there queries that have to act across databases?

Comment: no. there are no queries that that have act across the databases at this point.